# nvcc with avx support cannot find gcc builtin intrinsics

Tags: c, linux, cuda, nvcc, avx

This is my first question ;-)

I try to use AVX in CUDA application (ccminer) but nvcc shows an error:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -Xcompiler "-Wall -mavx" -O3 -I . -Xptxas "-abi=no -v" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" --maxrregcount=80 --ptxas-options=-v -I./compat/jansson -o x11/x11.o -c x11/x11.cu
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/avxintrin.h(118): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_addpd256" is undefined
```

[...]

This is just the first error. There are many 'undefined' builtin functions :-(

Everything is ok for 'C/C++' programs - with .c or .cpp extensions. But .cu - error :-( What do I do wrong ? I can compile ccminer but I cannot add AVX intrinsics to .cu files - only .c files. I use Intel intrinsics not gcc.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Linux Mint (ubuntu 13) 64bit, gcc 4.8.1, cuda 6.5.

I do not expect AVX to work on GPU. In .cu file there is small portion CPU based code which I want to vectorize.

Here is example to reproduce the error. I took the simplest example from:
http://computer-graphics.se/hello-world-for-cuda.html

Added line at the beginning:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
```

and tried to compile with the command:

```
nvcc cudahello.cu -Xcompiler -mavx
```

got an error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/avxintrin.h(118): error:
>   identifier "__builtin_ia32_addpd256" is undefined

The same code without `#include <immintrin.h>`
compiles without problems.

Here is whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if defined(__AVX__)
#include <immintrin.h>
#endif

const int N = 16; 
const int blocksize = 16; 

__global__ 
void hello(char *a, int *b) 
{
    a[threadIdx.x] += b[threadIdx.x];
}

int main()
{
    char a[N] = "Hello \0\0\0\0\0\0";
    int b[N] = {15, 10, 6, 0, -11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    char *ad;
    int *bd;
    const int csize = N*sizeof(char);
    const int isize = N*sizeof(int);

    printf("%s", a);

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&ad, csize ); 
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&bd, isize ); 
    cudaMemcpy( ad, a, csize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); 
    cudaMemcpy( bd, b, isize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); 

    dim3 dimBlock( blocksize, 1 );
    dim3 dimGrid( 1, 1 );
    hello<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(ad, bd);
    cudaMemcpy( a, ad, csize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ); 
    cudaFree( ad );
    cudaFree( bd );

    printf("%s\n", a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile with

> nvcc cudahello.cu -Xcompiler -mavx

to get the error or with

> nvcc cudahello.cu

to compile clean.

Comment: How do you expect Intel AVX instructions to work on an nVidia GPU ?

Comment: I see you have now edited the question to clarify a little - you need to either move the CPU-specific code out of the .cu file into a .c/.cpp file, or conditionally compile it for CPU-only.

Comment: @PaulR that is the usual advice.  Do you want to provide an answer (I would upvote).

Comment: Thanks. I am just a beginner in CUDA/vectorisation world.

So the general rule is to put only GPU part of code in .cu files while CPU based in .c/.cpp files. Correct ?

Comment: @baton: yes, that's more or less correct.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: my CUDA experience is a bit out of date so if you'd like to supply an answer then please go ahead (and I'll up-vote of course!) - I'm sure it will be more comprehensive than me just converting my comment to an answer.

Comment: I voted to close instead because OP did not provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which SO expects for this type of question ("why is my code not working").  If OP wants to provide a new question with an MCVE that I can compile and verify, then I'll provide an answer along those lines.  It's possible that there is some other issue with OP's code.  Without seeing an example, I don't want to sweep it under the rug.

Comment: added code to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an answer. Functions like:

```
_builtin_ia32_addpd256
```

are built into gcc and nvcc does not know about them. Since they are declared in `immintrin.h` nvcc returns errors while compiling .cu file with immintrin.h included. So we cannot mix cuda features with builtin gcc functions in one file.

Comment: Yep. I just came to a similar conclusion. in my case `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc  -fmad=true -arch=sm_20 -ftz=true -prec-div=false -prec-sqrt=false  -c -ccbin g++ -Xcompiler -mavx,-m64,-O3,-pipe,-D_CUDA,,,,"-I/usr/include/mpich2  -I/usr/include/mpich2" -std=c++11 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -use_fast_math  -m64 -I/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include -I.. cuda/cuda.cu -o cuda.o` gives that same error. (note the –mavx). The error is not shown in CUDA 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was actually fixed with CUDA 8, with the nvcc version shipping with CUDA 8 I can compile code that contains AVX intrinsics (which I couldn't with older versions).